# How to open g.i.cs file in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, designer

I'm building Windows Phone 7 App. I know that `g.i.cs` file is used to create UI object from XAML.

When right click on `InitializeComponent()` and select **Go to definition**, I can see the `g.i.cs` file. Is there another way to open it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the file from the directory obj/Debug of your solution.
I don't think you can open it with the solution explorer, this file is created during compilation.

Comment: This file is created during compilation? But I can edit it !?

Comment: I don't think so ^^. Create a new solution and add an useless int like int i = 0; in the InitialiazeComponent method and try to compil. I tried it and get an error, i must reload the file.

Comment: I think VS should lock that file

Comment: You may be able to see the file in the Solution Explorer by clicking on the `show all files` icon. But modifying the file is pointless since your changes will be overwritten the next time you compile the project.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to see the file in the Solution Explorer by clicking on the `show all files` icon and going to `obj / Debug / file.g.i.cs` .